# SharePoint Designer Workflow - Manager of Manager Look-up

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow, and I'm trying to look-up managers of managers. So far I have been able to successfully go two levels deep, but after that the workflow seems to stop looking any further. Is there a way to look up further managers?

Here is a screenshot of my setup:
[image: multiple manager lookup]

EDIT: I have figured out a way to obtain this functionality. A blog post in the near future will document the process.

Comment: Hello. Any word on how you got this to work? I'm not having luck getting the manager's manager...